# how do i link one directory to another directory so that FTP or SMB share can still use that directory

Tags: symlink, ln, shared-folders

Needing to link a SMB share directory to a empty directory with a FTP share. There is a empty directory inside of `FTP_Share1` called `smbshare` which I am trying to link to `SMB_Share1` to access all of those directories/files.

```
[root@freenas /mnt/Mike_Volume]# ls -l                                          
total 37                                                                        
drwxrwxrwx   5 root  FTPgrp   5 Jul 12 12:18 FTP_Share1                         
drwxrwxrwx   3 root  wheel    3 Jun 26 21:42 NExtCloud_Share1                   
drwxrwxr-x   2 root  Shares   2 Jun 26 11:28 NFS_share1                         
drwxrwxr-x  10 root  Shares  10 Jul  9 22:19 SMB_Share1                         
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  wheel    7 Jun 26 15:48 jails                              
[root@freenas /mnt/Mike_Volume]#

#ls -l FTP_Share1
total 19                                                                        
drwxrwxr-x  4 mike  FTPgrp  5 Jul 12 10:36 Mike                                 
drwxrwxrwx  5 mike  FTPgrp  5 Jul 11 16:20 Support                              
drwxrwxrwx  2 root  FTPgrp  2 Jul 12 12:24 smbshare                             
[root@freenas /mnt/Mike_Volume/FTP_Share1]#
```

`smbshare` is a new empty directory.
So i have tried using

```
#ln -s /mnt/Mike_Volume/SMB_share1 smbshare
```

this creates the symbolic link successfully

```
[root@freenas /mnt/Mike_Volume/FTP_Share1]# ls smbshare                         
SMB_Share1                                                                      
[root@freenas /mnt/Mike_Volume/FTP_Share1]# ls smbshare/SMB_Share1              
AmazonCloud             Downloads               dos stuff                       
DRIVERS                 Tools                   virtuals                        
Disk-Images             WinImagePortable                                        
[root@freenas /mnt/Mike_Volume/FTP_Share1]#
```

and you can cd or list the files within that symbolic link however when you attempt to FTP client it does not think that SMB_Share1 is a valid directory or even exists

```
{FTP DATA}
CWD /smbshare/SMB_Share1  
CWD /smbshare  
Transferred 98 bytes in 0.008 seconds  
CWD /smbshare/SMB_Share1/  
**550 /smbshare/SMB_Share1/: No such file or directory**  
PWD  
257 "/smbshare" is the current directory  
PASV
```

And windows FTP thinks its just a shortcut which does nothing but tries to download the link , either way i cannot access the files i need on the SMB_Share1 through FTP using `ln -s command`.  Any ideas?

[image: Windows FTP shortcut]

Comment: Maybe check the user rights (are login user and FTP/SMB server's users allowed to enter?) and that your servers are configured to allow following links.

Answer (score 0):

Try **bind** mounts.

Out of `man mount`:

Since Linux 2.4.0 it is possible to remount part of the file hierarchy somewhere else.  The call is:

```
mount --bind olddir newdir
```

or by using this fstab entry:

```
/olddir /newdir none bind
```

Comment: This does not work,  mount -bind indicates -b is a illegal operation  

[root@freenas /mnt/Mike_Volume/FTP_Share1]# mount -bind /mnt/Mike_Volme/FTP_Share1/smbshare /mnt/Mike_Volume/SMB_Share              
mount: illegal option -- b                                                                                                          
usage: mount [-adflpruvw] [-F fstab] [-o options] [-t ufs | external_type]

Comment: Would need to use `--bind` like I wrote